# How to animate between 2 scales in a zoom function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, scale

I want to transition when my state changes. The result I currently have is that my entire component is reload during zoom, I would like a smoother zoom. How can I do this?

I use react-tappable for detect pinch.

Here is my function :

```
// Zoom on pinch until maxScale, else resize to initial scale
handlePinchStart = () => {
const { scale, maxScale } = this.state;
if (scale <= maxScale) {
  this.setState(state => ({ scale: state.scale + 0.5 }));
} else {
  this.resize();
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this component a DOM element?

Comment: It's a function that I call as such:
`<Pinchable
 onPinchStart = {this.handlePinchStart}
 pressDelay = {2000}
 >`

Pinch corresponding to an element span of the Dom with the class "Tappable-active" or "Tappable-inactive" depending on the case.

Comment: Oh sorry I phrased that poorly. Is the animated scale referring to a DOM element?

Comment: No problem, I'm a beginner so I may be misinterpreted. No reference to the dom for the scale

Comment: Have you looked into CSS animations? That'll provide you with the smoothest zoom

Answer (score 0):

You can add or remove CSS class to your element which you want to zoom in or out, and do this according to your state. For example,

```
return (
   <div className={scale <= maxScale ? "my-element zoom-in" : "my-element"}>My Element</div>
)
```

It simply says, if your scale state is less than or equal to the maxScale, then make the className of your element **my-element zoom-in**, else make it just **my-element**. And in CSS, these classes can be like this:

```
.my-element {
   /* Some stylings for your element */
   transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.my-element.zoom-in {
   transform: scale(2);
}
```

As long as your scale state is <= maxScale, your element will have **.zoom-in** CSS class attached to it. And **.zoom-in** class simply makes your element's scale doubled. And thanks to putting `transition: transform 0.5s;` in your actual element's class(**.my-element**), it will grow smoothly and when scale is bigger than myScale, **.zoom-in** class will be removed, your element will only have **.my-element** class, and shrink back to its original size smoothly.

Comment: Thank you, it works well to animate the zoom but I always have a cut off time to re-render the component which is not very aesthetic. I have no idea how it is managed. This is what 
I have now :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-WkEn4oNoHw1M1YYiCKbnUxfdwt8Cgt/view?usp=sharing